# How to reuse Screen with different route.params React-Navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to reuse my home screen with different query, following is my code. But the `route.params` is undefined.

```
 //screen I want to reuse
 
const Home = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const route = useRoute();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  
  console.log(route);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.data) {
      console.log(route.params?.data);
      // Post updated, do something with `route.params.post`
      // For example, send the post to the server
    }
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const results = await DataStore.query(Product);
      setProducts(results);
    };
   
    fetchProducts();
  }, [route.params?.data]);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={products}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Post post={item} />}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToInterval={Dimensions.get('window').height - 70}
        snapToAlignment={'start'}
        decelerationRate={'fast'}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

```
const ProfileScreen = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  const route = useRoute();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const userid = route.params.data;

  //const picture = await DataStore.query(Post, "123");
  useEffect(() => {
    DataStore.query(User, userid).then(setUser);

    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const userProduct = (await DataStore.query(Product)).filter(
        c => c.user.id === userid,
      );
      //console.log('products', userProduct);
      setProduct(userProduct);
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  const thumbPress = post => {
    navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {data: post});
    console.log(post);
  };
  //console.log(product);
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.profile}>
          <Image source={{uri: user.imageUri}} style={styles.profilePicture} />
          <Text>{user.username}</Text>
        </View>

        {product.map((post, index) => (
          <View style={[styles.box]} key={index}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={thumbPress.bind(this, post)}>
              <Image source={{uri: post.images[0]}} style={styles.thumbnail} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default ProfileScreen;
```

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const RootNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeBottomTabNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            title: 'AuthScreen',
          }}
          name="AuthScreen"
          component={AuthScreen}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          options={{
            headerShown: true,
            title: 'Post',
          }}
          name="CreatePost"
          component={CreatePost}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{
            headerShown: true,
            title: 'Profile',
          }}
          name="ProfileScreen"
          component={ProfileScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            title: 'Camera',
          }}
          name="Camera"
          component={Camera}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{
            headerShown: true,
            title: 'Upload Options',
          }}
          name="UploadScreen"
          component={UploadScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            title: 'ProductScreen',
          }}
          name="ProductScreen"
          component={ProductScreen}
        />
       
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default RootNavigation;
```

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const HomeBottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        tabStyle: {
          borderStartColor: 'red',
        },
        activeTintColor: 'white',
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name={'Home'}
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => <Entypo name={'home'} size={24} />,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name={'Upload'}
        component={UploadScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <Ionicons name={'person-outline'} size={24} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name={'Search'}
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => <AntDesign name={'search1'} size={24} />,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name={'Profile'}
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <Ionicons name={'person-outline'} size={24} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

I'm new to react native and the navigation library as well. Thank you.

Comment: What is the issue with this code?

Comment: the home screen is not changing, when i console log params it shows undefined

Comment: have you destructured route as a prop?

Comment: `const route = useRoute();` `const navigation = useNavigation();` 
im doing this.

Comment: then that should work. Maybe update the question with the full components

Comment: yes, edited. please check

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/awDkoU34- Can you check this working example?

Comment: it says `Text strings must be rendered within <Text> component ` error.

Comment: Do you use prettier? If so, there might be {' '} this kind of symbol outside of the Text components.

Comment: i scanned it in to my device without editing or prettier

Comment: i edited the post with full component now. what im trying to do is to reuse the home screen to show profiles post.

Comment: okay I guess I found your mistake, I'll answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ProfileScreen, you are calling your thumbPress function immideately and also you are binding to this but it's not a class component. You should do something like this;

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => thumbPress(post)}>
          <Image source={{uri: post.images[0]}} style={styles.thumbnail} />
   </TouchableOpacity>
```

Also your home screen name is "Home" , you are routing to the "HomeScreen".

Comment: i fixed that part. but still when i log params on home screen it shows undefined. when i console.log it inside thumbPress i can see the data but not in home screen.

Comment: @VipulSanjay okay can you also add the stack navigator ?

Comment: sure, just did.

Comment: @VipulSanjay your home screen name is "Home" , you are routing to the "HomeScreen" , can that be wrong?

Comment: dudeeeee. hell yea. you are a genius man. :). yea i added `HomeScreen` to stack navigator and changed the thumbPress to HomeScreen and its now i can see the params. :) thanks man. i really was very stressed over this

Comment: @VipulSanjay can you also mark this as answer? thanks

Comment: its says i need 15 reputation to vote. ill get it and mark.